# Convert momentjs methods to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I looking for help converting these momentjs methods to vanilla javascript.

```
moment().format('YYYY')
moment("2021-06-11").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
moment().add(2,'days')
moment().add(-30,'days')
moment(date1).isAfter(date2)
moment(date1).isBefore(date2)
```

Comment: what did you try ? maybe you should just read the documentation of the Date object. https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Didn't you just ask the same question?